# How to do custom gridview with colorful item

Tags: android, gridview, colors, simpleadapter

I'm newbie, I have read the article from here [How to do custom ListView with colorful items' backgrounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199795/how-to-do-custom-listview-with-colorful-items-backgrounds) and I try to do some tasks: I have a table in Sqlserver contains list of table, each table have the status(0,1,2,3). My problem is how to apply to each status a color. Here is my Code:

```
try {
            Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
            rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(command);
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = null;
            data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            while (rs2.next()) {
                HashMap<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                datanum.put("A", rs2.getString(name));
                datanum.put("B", rs2.getString(code));
                datanum.put("C", rs2.getString("TTBan"));
                // datanum.put("D", rs.getString("GiaVon"));
                data.add(datanum);
            }
            String[] from = { "A", "C" };
            int[] views = { R.id.txt_Name, R.id.txt_image_gridview};
            SAD = new SimpleAdapter(this, data,
                    R.layout.fragment_activity_list_table, from, views)
            {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    image = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_image_gridview);
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    String valueChosen = String.valueOf(gridviewTable.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    String[] k = valueChosen.split(", B=");
                    String h = k[1];
//                  String[] tables = h.split(",");
//                  table = tables[0];
//                  System.out.println("Ma Ban la: " + table);
                    String[] g = h.split(", C=");
                    String l = g[1];
                    String status = l.replace("}", "");
                    System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  " + status);
                    if (status == "0" || status == null) {
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }if(status == "1"){
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    }if(status == "2"){
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                    }if(status == "3"){
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                    return view;
                }
            }
            ;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            String err = (e.getMessage() == null) ? "Error occured" : e
                    .getMessage();
            Log.e("Erro", err);
        }
        gridviewTable.setAdapter(SAD);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, The code is correct but I was wrong when i used if statement. So I edited it like this and everything is fine:

Replace this

```
                 if (status == "0" || status == null) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }if(status == "1"){
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                }if(status == "2"){
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                }if(status == "3"){
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
```

With this:

```
             if (status.equals(String.valueOf(0))) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } else if(status.equals(String.valueOf(1))){
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }else if(status.equals(String.valueOf(2))){
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }else if(status.equals(String.valueOf(3))){
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    }else{
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
     return view;
     }
```