# How to initially hightlight some row items in ListView?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simpleadapter

I'm populating a `ListView` with the data from a SQLite database and then I use `SimpleAdapter` to display it. One of the fields of each row is a `String` which refers to a color. I want to set the background color of each row according to that `String`. How can I do that?

**Edit:** I added the code I'm using to attach my data to the ListView:

```
listView_commentaires = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liste_favoris);
        daofavoris = new DAOFavoris(FavorisActivity.this);
        daofavoris.open();
        List<Commentaire> response = new ArrayList<Commentaire>();
        response = daofavoris.getAllFavoris();
        try {
            favoris = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            for (Commentaire commentaire : response) {
                HashMap<String, Object> element;
                element = new HashMap<String, Object>()
                byte[] miniature = commentaire.decodeMiniature();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(miniature, 0, miniature.length);
                element.put("BITMAP", bitmap);
                element.put("CONTENT", commentaire.getContent());
                element.put("AUTHOR", commentaire.getAuthor());
                element.put("DATE", Constantes.getRealDate(commentaire.getDate()));
                favoris.add(element);
            }
            simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(FavorisActivity.this,
                    favoris, R.layout.favoris_liste, new String[] {
                            "BITMAP", "CONTENT", "AUTHOR", "DATE" },
                    new int[] { R.id.media_favoris,
                            R.id.favoris_content,
                            R.id.favoris_author,
                            R.id.favoris_timestamp });
            simpleAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
                @Override
                public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                        String textRepresentation) {
                    if ((view instanceof ImageView)
                            & (data instanceof Bitmap)) {
                        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;
                        Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data;
                        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            listView_commentaires.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `SimpleAdapter`, you could use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` like this:

```
  SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(
      getActivity(),
      R.layout.yourLayout,
      yourCursor,
      new String[] {
        YourColumnName
      },
      new int[]{
        R.id.your_root_layout_element
      }, 0
    );

  adapter.setViewBinder(
    new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
      @Override
      public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) view;
        setBackgroundColor(
          Color.parseColor(
            cursor.getString(0)));
        return true;
      }

    });
```

where:

- `R.layout.yourLayout` is the layout resource that you use for each row of your `ListView`;
- `yourCursor` is the `Cursor` that contains the data received from the database;
- `yourColumnName` is the `String` representation of the column name where you have the color;
- `R.id.your_root_layout_element` is the id assigned to the root element of your layout. In this example I have assumed that it is a `LinearLayout`;
- `Color.parseColor(cursor.getString(0))` generates the color identifier from the `String` taken from the database.

After that, you have to assign this `SimpleCursorAdapter` to your `ListView` as follow: `listView.setAdapter(adapter);`.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you, however I already use setViewBinder because I set a Bitmap according to another String field of each row: `simpleAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
      String textRepresentation) {
     if ((view instanceof ImageView)
       & (data instanceof Bitmap)) {
      ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;
      Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data;
      iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
      return true;
     }
     return false;
    }
   });`

Answer (score 0):

inside adapter class put this code:

```
convertView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.message_selector_holo_blue));
```

according to condtion change the color of row

Comment: This assumes that I use a custom Adapter? I'm just using SimpleAdapter.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199795/how-to-do-custom-listview-with-colorful-items-backgrounds

Comment: I refered to the link but the app crashes because of some NullPointerException in `getView`

Comment: After reading some documentation I saw that convertView is null when the relative View is on the screen. The row has to be out of the screen. Then that solution can't work in my case, because I need to apply color changes to the whole list at the very beginning.