# Listview background color not getting updated

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I have following listview:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >
    </ListView>
```

I want to update background color of its first nth columns.

For that i am using:

```
int numOfMessages=lst.length-lstNew.length;  
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Messages.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst);
lm.setAdapter(adpt);
for (int i=1;i<numOfMessages;i++)
{
tv.setText("Welcome " + i);
lm.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
tv.setText("Welcome :  " + i);
}
```

But there is something wrong with line:

```
lm.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Because after that control is not moving further.

Please help me to change the background color of textview dynamicaly.

Comment: Write custom ArrayAdapter as decribed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008571/custom-arrayadapter-setbackground-in-getview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get it By:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Messages.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            if(position==2){
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }else if(position==4){
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } 
            return v;
        }
    };
```

Something Like this for that row which you want....

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Messages.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                return v;
            }
        };
```

Comment: giving me error on ViewGroup... ViewGroup can not be resolved as a type

Comment: import it `import android.view.ViewGroup;` , or click `ctrl+shift+o` to fix imports.

Comment: sir, app is not running, it is not showing me loginform, nor showing me anything in logcat, plz guid me

Comment: restart eclipse, restart emulator

Comment: This worked, but only problem is it applies background to all the listview..i want it to get to particular rows only

Answer (score 0):

firstly you should convert lm.getChildAt(i) to here specifique type ...
Exemple : if lm.getChildAt(i) is a textview write like that:

```
TextView txtv1 = (TextView)lm.getChildAt(i);
txtv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```